Guidance for simulating piezoresistive material with different probing electrodes
I am trying to simulate several piezoresistive materials to be used as tactile sensors.
A sheet of the material (Like Velostat for example) is to be placed on top of two electrodes, pressure on the material will alter the resistance between these two electrodes, which I can then calibrate to measure pressure.
I need some guidance on how I would simulate this effect in FEM software, guidance on software choice or material to read would be very appreciated.
Thanks alot.

